# Bootstrap4 modal adds padding-right:17px after closing modal

Tags: bootstrap-4, bootstrap-modal

when bootstrap modal is opened and close it adds padding-right:17px; to the body

i tried with below code. but couldn't fix

`.model-open{
padding-right: 0 px !important;
}`

Comment: `0 px` is invalid. Do without white space `0px`

Comment: Pls check your code. When bootstrap modal closed, body doesn't have the class `.model-open`. It's removed auto

Comment: i tried it. but its not working. but after modal closed padding remains same of 17px and it increments as i open modal n times.

Comment: can you share your code? it works well in https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap4/tryit.asp?filename=trybs_modal&stacked=h